# ngModel no funciona con datepicker. Angular

Tags: materialize, datepicker, angular5

soy nuevo en angular y me he encontrado con este problema. No funciona ngModel cuando utilizo la clase datepicker en el input. Alguna solución? o que estoy haciendo mal?

```
<div class="input-field  col s12 m6 l6 xl6">
     <input id="fecha_inicio" type="text" class="datepicker" formControlName="fecha_inicio" [(ngModel)]="ciclo.fecha_inicio">
           <label for="fecha_inicio">Fecha inicio</label>
           <div *ngIf="formCiclo.controls.fecha_inicio.errors?.required && (formCiclo.controls.fecha_inicio?.touched || submitted)" class="error">
                            El fecha inicio es requerida
           </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El *$scope* con **ng-model** , no interpreta el valor que seleccionas en el datepicker y para recoger su valor, hay que recogerlo por id, de la siguiente forma:

```
$("#fecha_inicio").val()
```

Y si quieres asignarle un valor:

```
$("#fecha_inicio").val("21/02/2018")
```